# How to create and process a form with multiple same fields?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm really stuck with this. To show my problem I created a new Django project and started from scratch, focusing only on one single form.

What I'm trying to do is to create a form with several fields of the same name. I tried using `modelformset_factory` to achieve this but it looks to me like it's not what I really need.

Below is my code (also on [dpaste](http://dpaste.com/836293/)) which currently works fine with one single field called `name`. How can I create and process a form which would have several `name` fields? Could somebody point me in the right direction?

```
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Ingredience Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# forms.py
class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)

# views.py
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        catform = CategoryForm(request.POST)
        catformInstance = catform.save(commit = False)
        catformInstance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        catform = CategoryForm() 

    context = {'catform': catform}
    return render_to_response('home.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# home.html template
<h3>Insert new Category</h3> 
<form action="/" method="post" id="ingr-cat-form">{% csrf_token %}
{{ catform.as_p }}
<input type="submit" name="ingrCatForm" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**UPDATE:** to clarify, I want to allow user to insert several categories within one form. I think I'm getting close, here is my **new version of views.py** but it still stores just one category (the last one in the list):

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        catform = CategoryForm(request.POST)
        names = request.POST.getlist('name')
        catformInstance = catform.save(commit = False)
        for name in names:
            catformInstance.name = name
            catformInstance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        catform = CategoryForm() 

    context = {'catform': catform}
    return render_to_response('home.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have fields with the same name (on the same Model). If you only need to change the html label in the html form, use

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    name2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, verbose_name="name")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
```

or

```
class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self , *args, **kwargs):
        super(CategoryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name2'].label = "name"
```

Comment: I don't want to add another field to the model. I want to allow user to insert several `name` values within one form.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: follow this tutorial http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I followed the tutorial but can't even get the form to display multiple fields. Here is how I'm doing it (see the else block: http://dpaste.com/836380/

Comment: catform is a list of forms. do something like : {% for catform_instance in catform %} {{ catform_instance.as_p }} {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. Thanks to @YardenST for pointing me in the right direction. I managed to solve my initial problem by following [this tutorial](http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/).

```
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Ingredience Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

# forms.py
class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)

# views.py
def home(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    catforms = [CategoryForm(request.POST, prefix=str(x), instance=Category()) for x in range(0,3)]
    if all([cf.is_valid() for cf in catforms]):
        for cf in catforms:
            catformInstance = cf.save(commit = False)
            catformInstance.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
else:
    catform = [CategoryForm(prefix=str(x), instance=Category()) for x in range(0,3)]

context = {'catform': catform}
return render_to_response('home.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


# home.html template
<h3>Insert new Category</h3>
<form action="/" method="post" id="ingr-cat-form">{% csrf_token %}
{% for catform_instance in catform %} {{ catform_instance.as_p }} {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" name="ingrCatForm" value="Save" />
</form>
```